# ngOnInit service data not working on constructor in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 5. Please help me. I tried to use angular service data available in ngOnInit() inside the constructor. I got response and stored in this.users. but i have used this.users  code inside constructor. it's not working

Below is my constructor Code.

```js
constructor(private dataService: DataService,private fb: FormBuilder) {


this.myForm = this.fb.group({
users: this.fb.array([])
})

let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
'name': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].name,Validators.required),
'category': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].category)
}));

let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
formArr.push(fb.group({
name: this.users[0].name,
displayOrder: this.users[0].displayOrder,
data: dataArr
}));
}
```

and below is my ngOnInt code:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getArchList()
.subscribe(data => this.users = data,
error => this.errorMsg = error
);
}
```

Please tell me how to approach while page load i have to use this.users.

Comment: NOT put the code to create the form in the constructor. Make a function and call the function in the subscribe (after equal this.user=data)

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that accesses `this.users` to `ngOnInit()` inside `.subscribe()`.

The constructor is called before `ngOnInit()`, and .`subscribe(data => this.users = data...` is executed asynchronous, therefore `this.users = data` has not executed when you are trying to access `this.users[0].data[0]` in the constructor.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getArchList()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.users = data;
       //Your code that accesses this.users
    }, 
     error => {
       this.errorMsg = error
    }
);
}
```

[image]

Take a look [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).